# Chance of a particular alphanumerical string of length 6 being a substring of a uniformly random alphanumerical string of length 13?

Tags: probability

What is the chance of a particular alphanumerical string of length 6 being a substring of a uniformly random alphanumerical string of length 13 in the case of:

http://www.newshub.co.nz/home/world/2017/09/australia-sends-out-same-sex-marriage-survey-with-barcode-bumsex.html

noting that it went out to a total of 16 million respondents only and also that the 6 sequential letters could start at any position from position 1 to position 8?

Comment: I don't think 'set' is the word your looking for. That has a very specific meaning. I believe what you _want_ to ask is about the chance of a particular alphanumerical string of length 6 being a substring of a uniformly random alphanumerical string of length 13.

Comment: @orlp Agreed and edited.

Comment: The use of the word alphanumerical suggests that each position in the string could be filled in $36$ ways since it could be replaced by one of the $26$ letters in the alphabet or one of the $10$ decimal digits.

Comment: BTW, I know that total outcomes could be 36^13 but I wonder if that should instead be 16,000,000 since the survey was only posted to that many people. – user1946932 26 mins ago

Comment: Actually if it was only posted to two people then total outcomes wouldn't be two so I don't think my comment about 16 million people applies.

Comment: I am not sure why you linked to the newspaper page you did.  Did you mean to provide a link to the specific problem?

Comment: Yes. It got truncated for some reason. Here it is: http://www.newshub.co.nz/home/world/2017/09/australia-sends-out-same-sex-marriage-survey-with-barcode-bumsex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that each of the $13$ positions in the alphanumeric code can be filled with one of the $26$ (uppercase) letters of the English alphabet or one of the $10$ decimal digits, there are $36^{13}$ possible $13$-character strings, as you stated in the comments.

As you observed, a particular $6$-character string must begin in one of the first $8$ positions.  Each of the remaining seven positions can be filled in $36$ ways.  Hence, there are $8 \cdot 36^7$ strings containing the particular $6$-character string.

In this case, the string BUMSEX that prompted the question could appear twice (there could be even more appearances if the string were ABABAB).  Therefore, we have counted such sequences twice. How many such sequences are there.  Since two appearances of BUMSEX account for $12$ characters, we have $36$ ways of choosing that character and $3$ ways of placing it (before both appearances of BUMSEX, between them, or after both of them).  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 36$ strings in which BUMSEX appears twice.

My thanks to @Awkward for pointing out that BUMSEX could appear twice and that other sequences such as ABABAB could appear even more times.

Thus, the probability that the alphanumerical string BUMSEX appears in a $13$-character alphanumerical string is 
$$\frac{8 \cdot 36^7 - 3 \cdot 36}{36^{13}}$$

Comment: Thanks. Yes and that formula result could be multiplied by 16 million since the survey went out to 16 million people. So that would be a 1 in 600 chance. Multiply that also if you were wanting to find "rude or offending words" by say 600 (since there could be that many such words) and there could be a 100% chance that one of the 16 million survey recipients could receive a "rude word or phrase".